# Kendo UI Costom Copy/ Paste Grid like Excel and data source update

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel, kendo-ui

I'm trying to add in Kendo UI Grid Copy/ Paste functionality, which will allow to multiply some cells in many other selected cells or to multiply selected rows or to copy several columns and to multiply them somewhere in the same grid - pretty much Excel functionality. What I've done so far is in this `JS Bin - http://jsbin.com/xokabumuka/1/edit?html,output`
- prepopulate one copied cell value in the same column multiple times, but only in the front end. The same for the rows and of course only for plain text.

I have two problems actually:
**First problem** - *Currently for some reason, I don't know why, I'm loosing "el2" rowIdx on the second iteration. If for example I copy from productName column value "Tea" and select all the cells below in order to prepopulate "Tea" and there after the first iteration my rowIdx is -1*
**Second problem** - *How to copy and the nested widget if the selected copied cell has some - for example if column productName contains dropdownlist and I want to copy and paste it along with his data source etc.*

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found solutions on my both problems and will share them for all the others who want to make something freaking strange :D

**First problem solution** - extracted grid.dataSource.data()[e.rowIdx].set(e.colName, e.value) between both foreach cycles - for some reason it breaks current row index

```
$.each(copiedData, function(i, el) {
    var IdxNamesValues = []
    $.each(grid.select(), function(i2, el2) {
        var row = $(el2).closest("tr");
        var rowIdx = $("tr", grid.tbody).index(row);
        var colIdx = $("td", row).index(el2);
        if (el.cellIndex === el2.cellIndex) {
            var colName = $('#grid').find('th').eq(el.cellIndex).text();
            var value = el.innerText;
            IdxNamesValues.push({rowIdx, colName, value});
            el2.innerText = el.innerText;
        }
    });

    $.each(IdxNamesValues, function(i, e) {
        grid.dataSource.data()[e.rowIdx].set(e.colName, e.value);
    })
})
```

**Second problem solution** - I found out that I can get kendo widget by it's HTML representation. For example if I select a column with nested kendoDropDownList widget in there and click Copy I'm getting the below HTML. After that on it I can say `copiedData.find('.k-widget input').data("kendoDropDownList")` to get that kendoDropDownList as an object with it's all options, dataSource etc...

```
    <td class="k-state-selected" role="gridcell" aria-selected="true">
   <span title="" class="k-widget k-dropdown k-header" unselectable="on" role="listbox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-owns="" aria-disabled="false" aria-busy="false" aria-activedescendant="f9fc2fa4-2c3d-4d9c-beef-7d924706fa72" style=""><span unselectable="on" class="k-dropdown-wrap k-state-default"><span unselectable="on" class="k-input">Jane Doe</span><span unselectable="on" class="k-select" aria-label="select"><span class="k-icon k-i-arrow-60-down"></span></span></span><input data-role="dropdownlist" data-text-field="text" data-value-field="id" data-bind="value: name, source: items" style="display: none;"></span>
</td><td class="" role="gridcell">29</td><td class="" role="gridcell">testt</td>
```

I hope will save a lot of time on someone else : )